# I don't see all the photos I've shared on Messenger with a person in the chat Gallery. How to download them all?

Tags: facebook-messenger

It's a chat with long history (3 years and more) and many shared pictures during this period. Since recently the whole gallery was seen from the very beginning and now I see only 1 year back and the older pictures are missing in the gallery. I cannot also scroll the conversation so much back. How can I find and download all of them?

Comment: Are you unable to see message also for that period where pictures are missing? Try to download Facebook data and see if you get those pictures.